# $f,g$ are real valued functions on X .which of following options is true?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let$ (X,M,\mu )$ is a measure space and $f,g$ are real valued functions on X .which of following options is true?

1) if $|f|$ be measurable then $f$ is measurable.

2) if $f^n$ (for all $n>4$ and $n \in \Bbb{N} $) be measurable then $f$ is measurable.

3)if $f+g$ be measurable then $f-g$ is measurable.

4) if $f×g$ be measurable and $g(x) \neq 0 $  then $ \frac{f}{g} $ is measurable.

I find counterexamples for 1 and 3 if we set $ f(x)= 1 $ if $ x \in A$ otherwise $f(x)=-1$ (that A is a non measurable subset of X) then $|f(x)|=1$ and 1 is false . For 3  $ f(x)= \chi _ A $ and $ g(x)=  - \chi _ A $ and for 2 we know that $k(x)= \sqrt[5] {x} $ is measurable function so $f$ is measurable function .I can't find counterexample for  4.

Comment: Your counter example for 1 isn't right. In the case you wrote, $|f| =f$, which is not measurable.

Comment: @user332239. Yes .now is true.

Comment: If you give me the definition of measure I can probably give you an answer. I am very smart.

Comment: @Alephnull. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)

Comment: Your example for the first part (i.e. $f = \chi_A - \chi_{A^C}$) also works for the second part because $f^6 = 1$ is measurable (so the second is false). Now the fourth one is interesting. I suggest you delete the question and post a new question where you only ask about the fourth one (to get more attention)