# is $\frac{f}{g} $ measurable with this condition ...

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let$ (X,M,\mu )$ is a measure space and $f,g$ are real valued functions on X .

Prove or disprove : if $f×g$ be measurable and $g(x) \neq 0 $  then $ \frac{f}{g} $ is measurable.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Right now, it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: Hi . @GregMartin. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2002386/f-g-are-real-valued-functions-on-x-which-of-following-options-is-true

Comment: Questions should be self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be a non-measurable set, and put $$f=2\times1_E+1_{E^c},\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ g=\frac12\times1_E+1_{E^c}.$$
Then
$$
f\times g = 1, 
$$
measurable. But
$$
\frac fg=4\times1_E+1_{E^c},
$$
not measurable.